# Why does this not error out?

Tags: jquery

I saw this in code today and I am kind shocked that it does not produce an error

```
if($('.MyClass'))
{
  // do stuff here
}
```

So it is a jquery selector inside a if statement. According to firebug if the selector is not found it returns null. If it is found it returns the dom object.

So from what I can tell it always goes into the if statement but I am kind a more shocked that it does not error out.

If in C# you tried to just have an object or null in an if statement I don't think it would compile.

I was expecting at least an error to show up in firebug.

Comment: Every call to `jQuery` (at least with a selector) returns a jQuery object. Objects always evaluate to `true`. Don't forget that JavaScript is dynamically typed. And in this particular case, you have a syntax error *Edit: Not anymore*.

Comment: I get an error in chrome: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: Exactly... you can't start a variable name with `.`

Comment: Aaaaannnnd... OP update the code invalidating everything I've been saying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't error out because (I'm assuming, of course, that you mistyped your question and you have quotes around your class name like `if($('.MyClass'))`):

```
if(null){
    // Do something
}
```

Is valid syntax in JavaScript (although it may not do what you expect it to do).

JavaScript will try to cast null to a boolean value. When that cast happens, JavaScript specifies that the cast should return `false`.

Comment: @hunter - That's because the OPs code isn't valid. I'm assuming in my answer that they simply forgot to type the quotes.

Comment: OP changed his question... nevermind... at least I'm not crazy, at least in this case

Answer (score 2):

I'd be more afraid about the quotes:

```
if($('.MyClass'))
{
  // do stuff here
}
```

If **THAT** were the case, then it would be completely valid. In JavaScript (I think), anything which isn't `0` or `null` or `false` is `true`, which means that the jQuery object will evaluate to `true` if it exists, and to `null` (which evaluates to `false`) if it does not.

Comment: I get `Unexpected token '.'` which makes sense because I don't think you can start a variable name with a `.`

Comment: @hunder - I am using it as a selector that should be valid. $(".myClass")

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - ah I forgot to write them in.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question **does** produce a syntax error.

Perhaps you mean

```
if($('.MyClass'))
{
  // do stuff here
}
```

(*notice the quotes around the `.MyClass`*)

This works because jQuery returns an empty object if nothing matches the selector. But an object none the less.. so the code in the if will always be executed..

Useful syntax would be

```
if($('.MyClass').length)
{
  // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not C#.

`if (X) {}` (where `X` evaluates to `null`) is perfectly valid syntax.

And it doesn't matter, because the selector will never be `null` anyway. It's an object, and objects always evaluate to `true`.

<strike>That all said, I'd expect hell and torture from `if ($(.MyClass))` because it's not `if ($('.MyClass'))`.</strike>

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - So if it does not find anything that matches it still returns an object what makes it true? 
So null == true?

Comment: @chobo2: `null` has _nothing to do with it_. The selector is an object. That it contains an empty collection of nodes is an internal property which does not affect the dynamic type of the object itself. It's not like some low-level C linked-list pointer. :)

Comment: @chobo: No, it does not return `null`. It returns an object. Where did you read that `null` is returned?

Comment: @ Felix Kling - Thought firebug was returning null but now it seems to have any empty array( [] ). However if I do this now if($('.MyClass')){} I get undefined.

Comment: @chobo2: You're using Firebug wrong. Use the jQuery documentation as your authoritative source until you learn to use your tools. I don't say this to be mean, but to help you. :)

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal  - Wrong in what way? I usually use it see what selectors return back. It's alot faster then writing the selector in code and alerting it out.

Comment: @chobo2: Selectors don't evaluate to `null`, so your usage is wrong in that way. As for how you drew this wrong conclusion... well I don't know. I can't see how you use Firebug. It's possible that you're examining some property _inside_ the selector object, rather than the selector object itself.